# Trouble with for loop continuing after catching an exception

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, inputmismatchexception

Hi I am semi new at java and cant figure this one out. After catching an exception I want a for loop to continue and keep reading for new integers. This was a challenge put online that wants you to take 
5 (this telling how many inputs it should expect after),

```
-150,
150000,
1500000000,
213333333333333333333333333333333333,
-100000000000000.
```

And turning into this output:

```
-150 can be fitted in:
* short
* int
* long
150000 can be fitted in:
* int
* long
1500000000 can be fitted in:
* int
* long
213333333333333333333333333333333333 can't be fitted anywhere.
-100000000000000 can be fitted in:
* long
```

I want the computer to check if a number will not be to large for a byte, short, int, and long. It works (maybe not in the best way) until it reaches 213333333333333333333333333333333333. It causes the InputMismatchException (bc its to large) and the code catches it but after it doesn't work. Here is the output:

```
 -150 can be fitted in:
 * short
 * int
 * long
 150000 can be fitted in:
 * int
 * long
 1500000000 can be fitted in:
 * int
 * long
 0 can't be fitted anywhere.
 0 can't be fitted anywhere.
```

I really cant figure it out any help would be appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numofinput = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    numofinput = scan.nextInt();
    int[] input;
    input = new int[numofinput];
    int i =0;

    for(i = i; i < numofinput && scan.hasNext(); i++){ 
        try {

            input[i] = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(input[i] + " can be fitted in:");

            if(input[i] >=-127 && input[i] <=127){
                System.out.println("* byte");
            }if((input[i] >=-32768) && (input[i] <=32767)){
                System.out.println("* short");
            }if((input[i] >=-2147483648) && (input[i] <=2147483647)){
                System.out.println("* int");
            }if((input[i] >=-9223372036854775808L) && (input[i] <=9223372036854775807L)){
                System.out.println("* long");
            }

        }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(input[i] + " can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the mismatched input remains unclaimed in the `Scanner` *after* the exception, so you are going to catch the same exception in the loop forever.

To fix this problem, your program needs to remove some input from `Scanner`, for example by calling `nextLine()` in the `catch` block:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    // Use scan.next() to remove data from the Scanner,
    // and print it as part of error message:
    System.out.println(scan.next() + " can't be fitted anywhere.");
}
```

The `input[]` array can be replaced with a single `long input`, because you never use data from prior iterations; hence, there is no need to store it in the array.

In addition, you should replace the call to `nextInt` with a call to `nextLong`, otherwise you are not going to process large numbers correctly.

You should also remove the condition for `long`altogether

```
if((input[i] >=-9223372036854775808L) && (input[i] <=9223372036854775807L))
```

because it is guaranteed to be `true` given that reading `nextLong` has completed successfully.

Finally, using "magic numbers" in your program should be avoided in favor of pre-defined constants from the corresponding built-in Java classes, for example

```
if((input[i] >= Integer.MIN_VALUE) && (input[i] <= Integer.MAX_VALUE))
```

instead of

```
if((input[i] >=-2147483648) && (input[i] <=2147483647))
```

Comment: If the nextInt method is throwing the exception, hasnt the input been claimed? His output would suggest that.

Comment: @BenKnoble I think OP truncated his output. `nextInt` leaves the data inside `Scanner` if it cannot process it ([demo](http://ideone.com/xi8BnT)).

Comment: Ok fair enough. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick reply but it still doesn't work i am receiving the same output as before.

Comment: @JTattack I made both changes to your code, and it worked fine. See demo [here](http://ideone.com/x5hVim).

Comment: Thanks so much it worked I cant tell you how long I spent trying (too long) to solve the problem. Glad it finally worked!

Comment: @JTattack You are welcome! Please take a look at the last edit to see how you can improve your code for better readability.